# Find an appropriate equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Set-Theory**

**Find an appropriate equivalence relation on $\mathbb R$:**

$1. \text{ Number of equivalence classes :} \mathfrak c , \text{ class cardinality : finite.}$

$2. \text { Number of equivalence classes : }\mathfrak c \text{ , class cardinality : } \mathfrak c,.$

$3. \text { Number of equivalence classes : }\aleph_{0} \text{ , class cardinality : } \mathfrak c.$

**My solution :**

$1. \text{ The equivalence relation is :} (a,b) \in R \iff a=b.$

There are $\mathfrak c$ equivalence classes , cardinality of each class is $1$.

$2.$ I'd be grateful for some help !

$3. \text{ The equivalence relation is :} (a,b) \in R \iff \lfloor a \rfloor=\lfloor b \rfloor.$

There are $\aleph_{0}$ equivalence classes , cardinality of each class is $\mathfrak c$.

Are my answers correct ?

Comment: Fixed it , thanks

Comment: I think op means the cardinality of real numbers.

Comment: Your two given answers are correct. For the middle one: this isn't the only way, but do you know a bijection $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$? If so, you could define $x\sim y\iff$ the second coordinate of $f(x)$ equals the second coordinate of $f(y)$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You are correct. I didn't think this through